# Finding Kneighbors in sklearn using KDtree with multiple target variables with multiple search criteria

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, kdtree

Lets say this is my simple KD tree alogrithm that I am implementing

```
def Test():

    features = np.random.random((10, 2))

    X = np.array(features[0:2])
    print(X)
    tree = KDTree(features, leaf_size=40)
    indic = tree.query_radius(X, r= 0.1)

    counter = 0
    for i in indic:
        a = (features[i])
        np.savetxt('file{}.txt'.format(counter), a, fmt='%s')
        counter += 1
        yield i

tree = Test()

[X for X in tree]
```

Here I am saving text file for each neighbor elements of that each target position and this work quite fine.

Are there any tricks that I can use different search criteria for each target points without creating a separate tree query again and again?

For example, lets say I want to use one variable `X = np.array(features[0]` with `r = 0.1`
and another variable `Y = np.array(features[1]` with `r = 0.5`
Right now, I can think only like this way

```
indic1 = tree.query_radius(X, r= 0.1)
indic2 = tree.query_radius(Y, r= 0.5)
```

Is there a way that I can combine these two and make a one tree query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way of doing it, using just one `query_radius` call, from the documentation:

> r can be a single value, or an array of values of shape x.shape[:-1]
>   if different radii are desired for each point.

So you can do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree

np.random.seed(42)
features = np.random.random((10, 2))

X = np.array(features[0:2])
tree = KDTree(features, leaf_size=40)
indices = tree.query_radius(X, r=np.array([0.1, 0.5]))

for cursor, ix in enumerate(indices):
    np.savetxt('file{}.txt'.format(cursor), features[ix], fmt='%s')
```

The output was file0.txt and file1.txt, file0.txt has 1 point (lower radius) and file1.txt has 5 points (higher radius).